# Setting the Editable property of a column in JQXgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jqxgrid

JS: http://jsfiddle.net/tzHXR/

```
 var data = generatedata(500);
 var source = {
     localdata: data,
     datafields: [{
         name: 'firstname',
         type: 'string'
     }, {
         name: 'lastname',
         type: 'string'
     }, {
         name: 'productname',
         type: 'string'
     }, {
         name: 'date',
         type: 'date'
     }, {
         name: 'quantity',
         type: 'number'
     }, {
         name: 'price',
         type: 'number'
     }],
     datatype: "array"
 };

 var adapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);
 $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid({
     width: 500,
     theme: 'energyblue',
     editable: true,
     source: adapter,
     sortable: true,
     columns: [{
         text: 'First Name',
         datafield: 'firstname',
         width: 90,

     }, {
         text: 'Last Name',
         datafield: 'lastname',
         width: 90
     }, {
         text: 'Product',
         datafield: 'productname',
         width: 170
     }, {
         text: 'Order Date',
         datafield: 'date',
         width: 160,
         cellsformat: 'dd-MMMM-yyyy'
     }, {
         text: 'Quantity',
         datafield: 'quantity',
         width: 80,
         cellsalign: 'right'
     }, {
         text: 'Unit Price',
         datafield: 'price',
         cellsalign: 'right',
         cellsformat: 'c2'
     }]
 });
```

I am trying to learn JQXgrid and this is my JS file. in this whole grid is set to editable: true flag but i want a particular field to be non-editable.

In reference to the forum-post by jqwidget team member http://www.jqwidgets.com/community/topic/making-a-column-non-editable/#post-11055

i tried this:
JS: http://jsfiddle.net/tzHXR/89/

```
 var data = generatedata(500);
 var source = {
     localdata: data,
     datafields: [{
         name: 'firstname',
         type: 'string'
     }, {
         name: 'lastname',
         type: 'string'
     }, {
         name: 'productname',
         type: 'string'
     }, {
         name: 'date',
         type: 'date'
     }, {
         name: 'quantity',
         type: 'number'
     }, {
         name: 'price',
         type: 'number'
     }],
     datatype: "array"
 };

 var adapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);
 $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid({
     width: 500,
     theme: 'energyblue',
     editable: true,
     source: adapter,
     sortable: true,
     columns: [{
         text: 'First Name',
         datafield: 'firstname',
         width: 90,
         editable:false; // Editable Property Set to false
     }, {
         text: 'Last Name',
         datafield: 'lastname',
         width: 90
     }, {
         text: 'Product',
         datafield: 'productname',
         width: 170
     }, {
         text: 'Order Date',
         datafield: 'date',
         width: 160,
         cellsformat: 'dd-MMMM-yyyy'
     }, {
         text: 'Quantity',
         datafield: 'quantity',
         width: 80,
         cellsalign: 'right'
     }, {
         text: 'Unit Price',
         datafield: 'price',
         cellsalign: 'right',
         cellsformat: 'c2'
     }]
 });
```

but after this , it doesn't work at all. all it shows is blank. i tried on my machine too.
why does `editable:false` for a column makes it worse. how can i apply non-editable property to one exact column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that you should remove ";" after editable: false in your jQWidgets Grid's column definition. That is a syntax error.